# The coface map on Amitsur's complex is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra

Let $S$ be a commutative algebra over a commutative ring $K$. Put $S^0=K$ and $S^n=S\otimes_K\cdots\otimes_K S$ ($n$ factors). In the Basic Algebra volume II, Jacbson says that the map $\delta^i: \otimes_{i=1}^nS\to\otimes_{i=1}^{n+1}S$ given by 
$$x_1\otimes \cdots x_n\mapsto x_1\otimes \cdots \otimes x_{i-1}\otimes 1\otimes x_i\otimes\cdots x_n$$
is an algebra isomorphism. (exercise 3 section 6.2.)

Is it really true? It seems to define a homomorphism, but are $S$ and $S\otimes_K S$ really isomorphic?

For example. Let's see $\mathbb{R}$ as an algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$. I don't see how $(\pi\otimes 1)\in\operatorname{Im}\delta^1:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: Where in the book is this claimed?

Comment: I'm not sure your last example is good... $\delta^2$ inserts $1$ in the $i $-th slot, so $\delta^2 (\pi)=\pi\otimes 1$?

Comment: What is not clear to me is if $\pi\otimes\pi \in {\rm Im}(\delta^2)$, say.

Comment: It was supposed to be $\delta^1$. I'll change. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion arises from Jacobson's outdated terminology. He says "isomorphism *into*", and by this he means an injection, i.e. he identifies $S^n$ as a subalgebra of $S^{n+1}$ via that map.